# Xamarin forms log in

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is this the correct way to log in via a web service call using **Xamarin Forms**?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.LOGINURL);

var response = client.PostAsync("Token", new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + _username + "&password=" + _password, Encoding.UTF8)).Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{   
    Application.Current.Properties["access_token"] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountAccess>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).access_token;            
}
```

The issue I am having is immediately afterwards I need to use the `access_token` to make web service calls to get more data.

Comment: Looks correct to me. How are you not able to use the `access_token` after making this call? Also I would suggest awaiting all `PostAsync()` and `ReadAsStringAsync()` instead of doing `.Result`

Comment: That's part of where I think I am getting an error. Since I immediately need to have access to access_token, I don't think the request has been finished for the next call to use it. I was hoping to see a synchronous method, but I don't see it.

Comment: If you `await` the code it should wait for those calls to finish and then continue with the rest of the code in that method. Could you include the code that would call the token post request you have written above?

Comment: Too much to put into here, but you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

you should `await` the `async` operation

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("Token", new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + _username + "&password=" + _password, Encoding.UTF8));

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{   
  // store token here     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple matter of awaiting async calls